# Querying an embedded attribute in Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm trying to query using Hibernate and running into some issues.

Let's say I'm trying to query the class `StoreEntity`, which has an embedded attribute `StoreInfo`.  `StoreInfo` is comprised of a Long `StoreNumber` and a Long `ManagerId`.

I have a `List<StoreInfo>` and I would like to return all of the associated  `StoreEntity`. I am trying to query like this:

```
Criteria criteria = this.session()
     .createCriteria(StoreEntity.class)
     .add(Restrictions.in("storeInfo", storeInfoList));
```

This only returns one result, which will be the first item in the StoreInfoList.

That said, if I break the `StoreNumber` and `ManagerId` fields into separate lists and search them with a conjunction, this works correctly.

```
final Conjunction criterion = Restrictions.conjunction();
criterion.add(Restrictions.in("storeInfo.StoreNumber", storeNumbers));
criterion.add(Restrictions.in("storeInfo.ManagerId", managerIds));

Criteria criteria = this.session()
        .createCriteria(StoreEntity.class)
        .add(criterion);
```

Why is this? I would understand if querying an embedded attribute with an *in* clause was just outright illegal, but why does it return one item? Should I always be using a conjunction when querying an embedded attribute?

I tried logging the actual queries to the console and got the following:

Working:

```
 [junit]          from
 [junit]              store_entity this_ 
 [junit]          where
 [junit]              (
 [junit]                  this_.store_number in (
 [junit]                      ?, ?
 [junit]                  ) 
 [junit]                  and this_.manager_id in (
 [junit]                      ?, ?
 [junit]                  )
 [junit]              )
```

Non-working:

```
 [junit]          from
 [junit]              store_entity this_ 
 [junit]          where
 [junit]              (
 [junit]                  this_.store_number, this_.manager_id
 [junit]              ) in (
 [junit]                  (
 [junit]                      ?, ?
 [junit]                  ), (
 [junit]                      ?, ?
 [junit]                  )
 [junit]              )
```

Seems like those should be the same?

Comment: Whether the second query works or not depends on the underlying database. Which database system and Hibernate dialect are you using?

Comment: The underlying database is Postgres and the Hibernate version 3.3.2. We don't have a dialect specified in the codebase but logs show it as ```org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect```. Seems like this could be the issue.

Comment: That could be the issues, also Hibernate 3.3.2 is pretty old.